# Fastest way to enforce a limit per UserId

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I have the interesting problem that I want to enforce a specific limit on how many offers a user can place. The offers are saved in a postgresql (version 10) database and should not exceed 1000.

I am using the following sql query to check how many offers a user has and check it against the limit:

```
select count(*) from offers where offers.userId = 'b27e1d2f-c2c1-4d0b-8451-287013d7b716';
```

In the performance metrics I see that most of the time is spent on this query. Therefore I looked it up and found this: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting

> PostgreSQL will still need to read the resulting rows to verify that they exist;

In the query planner it can be seen that additionally to the index only scan some **heap fetches** are needed which I assume slows down the whole query:

```
Index Only Scan using offers_by_user_id_index on offers
Index Cond: (account_id = 'b27e1d2f-c2c1-4d0b-8451-287013d7b716'::uuid) | Heap Fetches: 650
```

**- What are ways to speed this up?**

Is tracking the row count a good approach to speed up the check?

Thanks for your help!

Edit: UserId is an UUID and an index exists on the column UUID

Comment: you should have an index on `userid` and if that is a number (`int`) you should compare it with a number `'1'` is a string constant, `1` is a number

Comment: Actually the userId is an uuid and an index exists, but the time of counting still increases a lot depending how many offers are persisted.

Comment: Please show the original, complete execution plan (ideally generated using `explain (analyze, buffers)`, not a stripped down version where the import  parts were removed (and the formatted is screwed up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of heap fetches suggests that the table is not vacuumed often enough.  If you manually VACUUM it, does that speed things up?

Comment: The table is modified very frequently (insert/update/delete), could this be an issue?

Comment: Yes, it might be hard to keep it sufficiently vacuumed if it is updated extremely quickly.  But maybe you just need to change the autovac settings to be more aggressive.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will check what happens if the vacuum runs more often!

Comment: Indeed, as the table is very frequently changed the vacuum was not running often enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the right tool for that is de-normalization:

1. In table users add column offersCount
2. Create index on users table userid, offersCount

Add two triggers to the table offers

1. Insert trigger - will update users table and increase offersCount column
2. Delete trigger - will update users table and decrease offserCount column

With this there will be almost no latency

note: if you don't want to update user's table, just create new one, with only two columns

Comment: Here's an [example trigger for such summary table maintenance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56909231/15862).

Answer (score 0):

First, your ids are presumably numbers, so the comparisons should not be to a string.  So:

```
select count(*)
from offers
where offers.userId = 1;
```

For this query, I recommend a query on `offers(userid)`.  That might be a big help.

This might be a situation where storing the ids in an array is beneficial.  Then you can just add:

```
alter table users add constraint chk_offers check (array_length(offers) <= 1000)
```

This also changes how to insert and delete values.

For many purposes this will work well.  It does not work well if you care keeping lots of other information about the user/offer, such as creation date, offer date, channel, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The user id is an UUID, I updated the example. The offer has additional data, where should this be persisted then?

Comment: Does an index on `user_id` help the performance sufficiently?  Also, the question is not about additional information for the *offer*, but additional information for the *offer*/*user* combination.

Comment: Yes, the index helps. I added the result of the query planner and it tells me that it is an index only scan, but additionally heap fetches are shown...

Comment: With SQL if something is quoted, it does not mean that it's a string.